# powershell string contain only number

Tags: powershell

I have an array with folder names. I want to loop thru this array and find out if an entry is only 7 in length and only contain numbers.

Can anyone please push me in the correct direction? Thanks!

Comment: `$array -match '^\d{7}$'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is while looping through the array names check if the two conditions are met like so:

```
foreach ($name in "test", "1234567", "test02", "001") {
    if ($name.Length -eq 7 -and $name -match '^\d+$'){
        Write-Host $name
    }
}
```

Comment: I just came across this answer and it helped me. But I don't quite understand what '^\d+$' means. Why does this work?

Comment: @gwynbleidd that is the regular expression that covers the OP requirement for "capturing" numbers only. We have the two position anchors: leading (^) and trailing ($) and between one or more (+) decimals (\d). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understood your question :

```
function Is-Numeric ($Value)
{
    return $Value -match "^[\d\.]+$"
}

$birds = "owl","crow","robin","wren","jay","123"
foreach ($bird in $birds) { if($bird.length -eq 3 -and (Is-Numeric $bird)) {"$bird"} }
```

just switch it to your case :)